# jQuery Validation Plugin - Enable 'Eager' Validation only after and Invalid Submit

Tags: jquery, validation

By default, if a user enters a value in a field, the 'eager' validation kicks in. Is there any way to disable 'eager' validation before submit and then enable it after an invalid submit has happened?

I've used `$.validator.setDefaults()` to initially set the `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` properties to `false`.

In the `invalidHandler` method I rerun the `$.validator.setDefaults()`, setting `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` properties to `true`.

No luck with this approach.

Basically, I only want the 'eager' validation to take place after the user tries to submit an invalid form.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a simple solution. I just set a custom flag in the `invalidHandler` method and then check it in the other methods to determine what functionality to support.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {     
        // Set a custom flag to activate certain functionality
        // after the user has clicked the form submit.
        validator.settings.invalidSubmit = true;
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        // Check our custom flag
        if(this.settings.invalidSubmit) {
            // Do something...
        }
    }
});
```